# ClaimsAuthorizationManager - Authorize using request parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wif, claims-based-identity, c#-5.0

I have been looking at the ClaimsAuthorizationManager. If I had a claim that was the following:

Type = TypeOfEmployeesThatCanBeViewed, Value = "Managers"

Then I browsed to my MVC controller with mysite/employees/read/managers.  And I wanted to see if the currentprincipal was authorised to view managers.

How would you pass the actual request parameters i.e the "managers" to the ClaimsAuthorizationManager.  I can see how to pass "Read" and "Employers" via the Action and Resource properties of the AuthorizationContext, but not the parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thinktecture IdentityModel helper library is your friend. It provides a better API for doing claims based checks and then you could pass as many parameters as you want using **ClaimsAuthorization.CheckAccess** method.

So you should add the following line of code at the very beginning of your action method :

```
ClaimsAuthorization.CheckAccess("Read", "Employees", "Managers");
```

In ur CheckAccess method u can get Employees and Managers parameters from the context.Resource collection.

[Nuget Package Thinktecture.IdentityModel](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel)

[here is the documentation](http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/)

Comment: so you need to do this inline? Not ideal for cluttering up your business logic, but That makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Yea u r totally right, that's going to mess up ur SoC a little bit. Unfortunately, you can't pass multible parameters through the ClaimPermissionAttribute as far as I know.

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40/tree/master/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/Authorization